# Is there a bijective map between a simplex and $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is symmetric in all variables?

Tags: real-analysis

Wikipedia gives [this nice example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution#Multivariate_generalization) of a bijection between a simplex (set of vectors whose components are in $[0; 1]$ and sum to 1) and $\mathbb{R}^n$:

[image]

However, the last variable is somehow singled out and mapped *differently* than the other ones.

Is there a mapping that would be symmetrical in all variables?